# Qt: 'help' does work for searching qt class documentation in the qtcreator

Tags: qt

I have a static Qt5.9 built from the source and QtCreator4.5, and have used for days. These days, When I try to use `'help'` to search the documentation of qt class, no relevant results can be found, except those for QtCreator Manual. I come to realize that the documentation has yet to be added.

See the search results for `QFile` below:
[image]

My Qt is built with configurations as follows:

```
configure -static -debug-and-release -platform win32-msvc2015 -developer-build -opensource -nomake examples -nomake tests
```

The Qt is built using `jom` command. When I type 'jom install', it gives an error:

```
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-doc-install_subtargets] Error 2
```

Type 'jom generate_docs', and then get:

```
'C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\bin\qdoc.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
        C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug generate_docs
        call C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\corelib\qdoc_wrapper.bat -outputdir C:/Qt5.9/src-5.9.0/qtbase/doc/qtcore -installdir C:/Qt5.9/src-5.9.0/qtbase/doc C:/Qt5.9/src-5.9.0/qtbase/src/corelib/doc/qtcore.qdocconf -generate -indexdir C:/Qt5.9/src-5.9.0/qtbase/doc
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile.Debug [generate_docs] Error 9009
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\corelib\Makefile [debug-generate_docs] Error 2
        C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile.translator.Debug generate_docs
        cd libGLESv2\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\angle\src\libGLESv2\libGLESv2.pro ) && C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile generate_docs
        C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug generate_docs
        cd libEGL\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\angle\src\libEGL\libEGL.pro ) && C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile generate_docs
        C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\jom.exe -f Makefile.Debug generate_docs
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\src\Makefile [sub-corelib-generate_docs] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-src-generate_docs] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-qmake-qmake-aux-pro-generate_docs] Error 2
jom: C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase\Makefile [sub-doc-generate_docs] Error 2
```

Dose the built version support qt documentation? If so, what I need to set up to make QT class documentations available in the QtCreator?   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your `configure` is fine, as it does not contains `-nomake docs`.

When you have finished to compile and install Qt, you have to

```
make docs
make install_qch_docs
```

from the Qt's source root. You can set docs installation path with the `-docdir` parameter in `configure` (`-docdir /usr/doc/qt-<your-version>`)

When using `jom` on Windows system, you can use

```
jom docs
jom install_docs
```

or

```
jom generate_docs
jom qch_docs
jom install_qch_docs
```

Comment: I navigate the vs command prompt to the 'C:\Qt5.9\src-5.9.0\qtbase' and then type 'make docs', but get an error: 'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: then you should use 'jom generate_docs', 'jom qch_docs' and 'jom install_qch_docs'

Comment: there are some errors when type 'jom generate_docs', as you can see my edit post above.

Comment: Did you compiled qdoc?

Comment: there is no qdoc.exe in the qtbase/bin. Is that necessary for building documentation? How to get it?